# L1 penalty in sklearn's MLPRegressor?

Tags: scikit-learn, regularized

Is there a way to introduce L1 regularisation in sklearn's MLPRegressor? I can only find the L2 parameter in the documentation at the moment.

Comment: Nope, but the closest thing to scikit-learn that can do this is scikit-neuralnetwork –

Comment: thanks, switched over to keras for this particular application instead

Answer (score 0):

There is no L1 regularization for MLPRegressor as indicated in their documentation, but I think PyTorch or sknn will allow you to do this.